# Oracle Query don't see what's wrong

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run this Query but somehow the bottom part Label B doesn't work.

I am new to oracle and I just don't see what's wrong. Can anyone Please Help me? It would be much appreciated.

Its not returning any data when a salesperson is not tied to it. This should still return the information about the base customer regardless.

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.ship_sales_representative_id,
                X.ship_sales_representative_name,
                X.ship_sales_regional_name,
                X.ship_sales_regional_head,
                B.bl_customer_representative_id,
                X.sp_customer_representative_id,
                B.bill_customer_id,
                X.ship_customer_id,
                B.bill_customer_address_suffix,
                X.ship_customer_address_suffix,
                B.bill_customer_name,
                X.ship_customer_name,
                B.bill_customer_address,
                X.ship_customer_address,
                B.bill_customer_city,
                X.ship_customer_city,
                B.bill_customer_statecode,
                X.ship_customer_statecode,
                B.bill_customer_zipcode,
                X.ship_customer_zipcode,
                B.bill_customer_phonenumber,
                X.ship_customer_phonenumber,
                B.bill_customer_faxnumber,
                X.ship_customer_faxnumber,
                B.bill_customer_email,
                X.ship_customer_email,
                B.bill_customer_contact,
                X.ship_customer_contact
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT S.rep_id      Ship_Sales_Representative_ID,
                        S.rep_name    Ship_Sales_Representative_Name,
                        S.reg_name    Ship_Sales_Regional_Name,
                        S.reg_head    Ship_Sales_Regional_Head,
                        C.rep_id      Sp_Customer_Representative_ID,
                        C.cust_id     Ship_Customer_ID,
                        C.addr_suffix Ship_Customer_Address_Suffix,
                        C.name        Ship_Customer_Name,
                        C.addr_ln_1   Ship_Customer_Address,
                        C.city        Ship_Customer_City,
                        C.state_cd    Ship_Customer_StateCode,
                        C.zip_cd      Ship_Customer_Zipcode,
                        C.phone_nbr   Ship_Customer_PhoneNumber,
                        C.fax_nbr     Ship_Customer_FaxNumber,
                        C.email       Ship_Customer_Email,
                        C.contact     Ship_Customer_Contact
        FROM   mdw.customer C,
               mdw.sales_org S
        WHERE  C.rep_id = To_char(S.rep_id, 'FM000000')
               AND C.cust_id = v_cust_id
               AND C.addr_suffix = v_addr_suffix) X,
       (SELECT DISTINCT C.rep_id      Bl_Customer_Representative_ID,
                        C.cust_id     Bill_Customer_ID,
                        C.addr_suffix Bill_Customer_Address_Suffix,
                        C.name        Bill_Customer_Name,
                        C.addr_ln_1   Bill_Customer_Address,
                        C.city        Bill_Customer_City,
                        C.state_cd    Bill_Customer_StateCode,
                        C.zip_cd      Bill_Customer_Zipcode,
                        C.phone_nbr   Bill_Customer_PhoneNumber,
                        C.fax_nbr     Bill_Customer_FaxNumber,
                        C.email       Bill_Customer_Email,
                        C.contact     Bill_Customer_Contact
        FROM   mdw.customer C
        WHERE  C.cust_id = v_cust_id
               AND C.addr_suffix = '0001') B;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add at the end of the query:

```
WHERE X.REP_ID = B.REP_ID
```

(and remove the first `DISTINCT`) or another condition for the `JOIN` otherwise this query is going to return all the combinations of records in `X` with records in `B`

Since you're looking for

```
AND   C.CUST_ID     =v_Cust_ID
```

you should use it in the join!

Since you're not sure that the information exists in `X` you should use a `LEFT JOIN` on `X` which you can do in Oracle by:

```
WHERE B.CUST_ID = X.CUST_ID(+)
```

Comment: well the point is there B.REP_ID isnt join to begin with the whole sub table be is not running and returning NUll. I dont get how i can call a specific sub table and not get a result. but when i just run the Selct insub table b it works

Comment: @user2795514 It's not clear. Which sub-table is returning null ? what's the relationship between these sub-tables. You might want to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` - it depends on the kind of relationship between the sub-tables

Comment: The Two Tables Can't be joined together.

Comment: @user2795514 so what are they doing in the same query together ?

Comment: Its a stored procedure that is getting called by a web service they want both the information from Sub table X and Some information from Sub table B but if Subtable X doesnt return anything they still Want the Info from subtable b